# London Underground Tickets

Tags: public-transport, tickets, london

I am planning a visit to London for a couple of days. I will be staying at a hotel near Heathrow airport.

I am planning to use the underground as follows

1. Upon my arrival, from terminal 5 to Hounslow West, where my hotel is situated in
2. From Hounslow West to terminal 5, to meet a colleague
3. Then from Hounslow West to somewhere in central London, to see Big Ben and London's Eye(perhaps I will do this route once more, so 2 in total)
4. From central London to terminal 5

What's the best way to organize the tickets? Shall I buy a card? Is it better to use simple paper tickets?

In case it is better to buy a card, where to buy it from? Is there a possibility to get such a card in the airport? How much money should I load it with?

Note that I will be having Euros and not British Pounds, so I was wondering if Euros are accepted both for cards or paper tickets?

Comment: day travel cards are cheaper then a retour in more then one zone last time I was there. Day travel cards are valid for 24h and are obtained and used the exact same way as normal tickets. Euro's are generally not accepted, except for ticket booths manned by people(airport only), and you won't get any change.

Comment: @Gagravarr : I've already seen this questions. Its answers don't answer the following: "Where to get it?", "Can I get it from the airport upon my arrival?", "How much money should I load it with?", "Are euros valid?"

Comment: Any London Underground ticket office, Yes, about 20 quid and get a refund if there's any left, probably not but they take cards. See the links to various TFL resources and help from the duplicate question

Comment: @Thanos - Yes you can get from the airport, just make your way to the tube station. After all you are going to have to use the tube to go to Hounslow West(tube station). Ask the guy at the counter they will help. Once I tried to pay with USD. The person laughed and then took 2 minutes to compare and show me how USD and pounds are different. Buy a visitor Oyster card and have it posted to your address.